# Waiting for AngularJS initialization after using navigateTo

Tags: angularjs, testing, automated-tests, web-testing, testcafe

I've noticed that I *have* to use `navigateTo` for tests which use an already-authenticated user. If I define them with `.page` it just sends me back to the login screen because it seems like it can't see the role/state.

I assume that's intended but the documentation isn't as clear, but it's an assumption I've made which might impact my actual question.

I also believe that any `beforeEach` logic runs *before* the navigateTo method, which breaks logic we need to "waitForAngularJS".

I have a `waitForAngularJS` method which I adapted from the official `waitForAngular`. It works fine when used without authentication (when I can use `.page...`) but it doesn't run on the "navigated-to" page when I do use authentication.

```
fixture `demo1`
    .beforeEach(async () => {
        await waitForAngularJS();
    });

test('modal title', async t => {
    await t
        .useRole(regularUser)
        .navigateTo('http://127.0.0.1/some/page')
        // .. the "wait for angular" needs to run here, but can't
        .expect(Selector('.modal-title').innerText).eql('My Modal');
});
```

Putting a `.wait(1000)` in that spot solves my problem. When I use `.debug()` I can tell that the waitForAngular logic has not been run on the new page.

Edit: According to [the forums](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/api-how-to-use-the-roles-properly/534/7), the order of the logic is right:

> > opens the fixture page;
> >     executes the beforeEach function;
> >     executes the useRole command: goes to the role initialization page (the first argument of the useRole command), executes the initialization function and goes to the previously opened page as a registered user;
> >     resumes the test.

Answer (score 2):

An e2e test should be agnostic of the framework used to render the page. In my opinion you should not use methods like `waitForAngularJS`.
Just rewrite the expect statement like this:

```
await t
  .expect(Selector('.modal-title').innerText).eql('My Modal', {timeout: 10000});
```

You can also set the [assertion timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--assertion-timeout-ms) directly on the TestCafe command line.

Comment: I both agree and disagree but the agnostic piece is moot when using https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-angular-selectors .

Comment: This can work but it requires assertions to come before actions are taken. If I have to click to trigger the element, I need to explicitly add an "expect" prior to the `click()` which I've been using `.expect(Selector('.ng-scope').exists).ok()` for